# Setting of facebook app for invite friend

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite-friends

It may be an easy question, but I am tired of it

Is there any setting for Facebook app (Which we set while creating an App in Facebook developer's site) for making "invite friend" functionality to be worked.

I am using WebDialog method as follows,

FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                  message:FacebookInviteMessage
                                                    title:@"Invite Friends"
                                               parameters:parameters
                                                  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)

With the same method I am able to invite friend, when I am using the Facebook APP ID of another sample code in my project. But when I am using my own project's Facebook APP ID, invite is not working when I am getting Success in result url.

So I think there would be some setting in developer's site of Facebook.

Can anyone help for this

The complete code is

```
NSDictionary *parameters = self.fbidSelection ? @{@"to":self.fbidSelection} : nil;


MIDLog(@"self.fbidSelection %@",self.fbidSelection);

[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                              message:FacebookInviteMessage
                                                title:@"Invite Friends"
                                           parameters:parameters
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {

                                                  NSString *strResultUrl = [resultURL absoluteString];

                                                  if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogCompleted && ![strResultUrl isEqualToString:@"fbconnect://success"])
                                                  {
                                                      MIDLog(@"Web dialog complete: %@", resultURL);

                                                      if (![resultURL query])
                                                      {
                                                          return;
                                                      }

                                                      NSDictionary *params = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                                                      NSMutableArray *recipientIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                                      for (NSString *paramKey in params)
                                                      {
                                                          if ([paramKey hasPrefix:@"to["])
                                                          {
                                                              [recipientIDs addObject:[params objectForKey:paramKey]];
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                      if ([params objectForKey:@"request"])
                                                      {
                                                          NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", [params objectForKey:@"request"]);
                                                      }
                                                      if ([recipientIDs count] > 0)
                                                      {
                                                          //[self showMessage:@"Sent request successfully."];
                                                          //NSLog(@"Recipient ID(s): %@", recipientIDs);
                                                          UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Invitation(s) sent successfuly!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                                          [alrt show];
                                                          alrt = nil;
                                                      }





                                                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:FacebookInviteSuccess delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Proceed" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                      alert.tag = 14114;
                                                      [alert show];
                                                      alert = nil;

                                                      //                                                          [self navigateToSearch];
                                                  }

                                                  else if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogCompleted && [strResultUrl isEqualToString:@"fbconnect://success"])
                                                  {
                                                      MIDLog(@"Cancel Clicked");

                                                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancelled" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Proceed" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                      alert.tag = 14114;
                                                      [alert show];
                                                      alert = nil;

                                                  }

                                                  else {
                                                      MIDLog(@"Web dialog not complete, error: %@", error.description);

                                                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:InternetFailError delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                      alert.tag = 15115;
                                                      [alert show];
                                                      alert = nil;

                                                  }
                                              }
                                          friendCache:self.friendCache];
```

}

Thank you

Comment: Do you have your application in sandbox ? If so is user you are testing on in test users or administrator ? Also for sandbox mode it won't send an invitation to people outside sandbox - so you need 2 sanbdox users to test that.

Comment: NO, My sandbox mode is Disabled.
My Setting is 

Display Name : MyInstaDate
namespace name : myinstadate
Snadbox Mode : Disabled

Canvas Page : http://apps.facebook.com/myinstadate
Canvas URL : http://www.google.com/
Secure Canvas URL: http://www.google.com/

Facebook login : Enabled
Deep linking : Enabled
Appstore ID : 0

Comment: @Janmenjaya did you got solution for this?